# const { authenticated } = this.props is undefined though I can clearly see it in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

[image]
I have just copied some code from one project to another , and console.log("this is authenticated: " + authenticated) is returning undefined although i can see authenticated as true - in redux state (when i am in local host click right click inspect then go to redux then state.)

?

is this perhaps an issue with my version of react or redux?

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Proptypes from "prop-types";
import MyButton from "./util/MyButton";
import { logoutUser } from "./redux/actions/userActions";
import { getConversations } from "./redux/actions/dataActions";

//icons
import KeyboardReturn from "@material-ui/icons/KeyboardReturn";

///npm install @material-ui/core
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { auth } from "./firebase";

export class Navbar extends Component {
    render() {
        const { authenticated } = this.props;

        console.log("this is authenticated: " + authenticated);

        const { user } = this.props;

        return (
            <AppBar>
                <Toolbar className="nav-container">
                    {authenticated ? (
                        <Fragment>
                            <Link to="/login">
                                <MyButton
                                    tip="Logout"
                                    onClick={this.handleLogout}
                                >
                                    <KeyboardReturn color="primary" />
                                </MyButton>
                            </Link>
                        </Fragment>
                    ) : (
                        <Fragment>
                            <Button
                                color="inherit"
                                component={Link}
                                to="/login"
                                onClick={this.handleLogout}
                            >
                                {" "}
                                Login
                            </Button>
                            <Button
                                color="inherit"
                                component={Link}
                                to="/signup"
                            >
                                {" "}
                                SignUp
                            </Button>
                        </Fragment>
                    )}
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    authenticated: state.user.authenticated,
    user: state.user,
    conversations: state.data
});

const mapActionsToProps = {
    getConversations,
    logoutUser
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(Navbar);
```

Comment: More than likely, there is a disparity between the state passed and the state active.  Can you provide a screenshot of the `state` in `redux-devtools`?

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, why are you opting for a `class-based` component over a `functional` component. Hooks can massively simplify this process.

Comment: Hi Urmzd , i have added the picture and thanks i might try switching to functional components and hooks

Comment: A few more questions, before I can help. The first sanity check, is the redux-provider the parent of this component (in other words, is `NavBar` nested in the provider)? What does a `console.log` of `this.props` show?

Comment: ```<Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
        <Navbar />
       <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route exact path="/login"  >
         <Login />
</Route>
<AuthRoute exact path="/signup" >
         <Signup/>
</AuthRoute>
        </Router>
</Provider>```    is this what you mean by provider ?   and this.props logs {}

Comment: Add that code to your description, and I have an idea of what's going on. Will investigate and put and answer later.

Comment: ok thanks but I gave up and took your advice and changed it to a functional component and works fine now using 
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
const authenticated = useSelector(state => state.user.authenticated)
      thanks a lot

Comment: If the comment was useful, please give it a `+1`. I'll still try to get to the `class` component to work so you have a better idea how to go forward next time :)

Comment: Just to make sure. Can you provide the `imports` used in the `Provider`?

Comment: @vahidghadiri That makes no sense. You likely fixed a different problem when you removed the destructuring of the props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Background

When I say `named` and `default` exports/imports, I'm referring to `es-module` [exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) and `es-module` [imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

To simplify what the above article states, think of the two as such:

- `named` exports are `objects` which contain all the namespaces provided to it. For instance, `export const a; export const b;` will produce an object `{a, b}` which will be accessible to other modules by way of `import {a,b} from './file'` or other variants.
- `default` exports are just `named` exports that contain the `access modifier` `default` in it. In other words, it's just syntatic sugar which allows you to import the `default object` directly without destructuring and also provides you the ability to rename the object. For example `export default ReactInner` will allow you to `import React from "react"` without any errors. However, note that `ReactInner === React`.

### Answer

You're most likely importing the wrong component

```js
import {NavBar} from "../file"
```

which imports the named component (unconnected component, in your case).

Instead, you should have used

```js
import NavBar from "../file"
```

which imports the `default` component (the connected component, in your case)

The reason the functional component works is because `redux` uses `context` internally to connect the state of the component to the `redux` store. As a result, you don't require two exports and the exported components will always be connected.

Comment: @benpalmer If my notes helped (along with this answer), please upvote it and accept it as the answer :)

Comment: thanks , and what is the difference between { Navbar } and Navbar / putting it in brackets?

Comment: @benpalmer added explanation for the difference (in my answer)

Comment: so what is the difference between a named component/unconnected component and a default component/connected component?    or could you dumb it down for me just so it's ingrained in my memory ?

Comment: @benpalmer Read the background :)